# Managing complex SQL queries in ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment

**Context**

I am using ARM templates to deploy my resources to Azure and as part of this, I have a DataFactory with several SQL queries which are quite long.

**Problem**

It's quite annoying to always have to scroll-across/copy/paste/format when I need to change the queries. It's hard to maintain.

**Question**

Does anyone know a more efficient way of managing these queries in ARM templates? Is there a way of loading these from sql files upon deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing them externally and passing in as a base64 encoded string (to prevent escape hell) with powershell\python\whathaveyou and decode directly in the template with `base64ToString()`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#base64tostring